# while loop is itterating even though the expression is false in python

Tags: python

I want the loop to ask for name and amount and according to the users choice if they want to countinue, if user enters 'y' the loop should countinue else if user enters 'n'then the loop should terminate, but if I enter 'n' the loop is doesn't stop itterating.

```
import os


bidders={}

to_countinue=True

while to_countinue:

    name=input("Enter your name:\t")
    amount=int(input("\nBidding Amount:\t"))

    bidders[name]=amount

    count=input("\nIs there any other bidders (y/n):\t").lower

    if count=="n":
        to_countinue=False

    os.system('cls')

max=0
won=""
for key in bidders:

    if bidders[key]>max:
        max=bidders[key]
        won=key

os.system('cls')

print(f"The biiding was won by{key} with {max} bidding amount")
```

Comment: Remove the `cls` and try printing the value of `count` at the end of your loop instead.  Does it ever equal `"n"`?

Comment: `.lower` needs to be `.lower()`. Right now, `count` is an uncalled function, not a string.

Comment: you meant `count=input("\nIs there any other bidders (y/n):\t").lower()`?

Comment: Though not relevant to the issue at had, the correct phrase would be `Are there any other bidders?` and the word you're looking for is `continue` rather than `countinue`. I hesitate to bring that up since you may not be a native English speaker but I'm trying to help out with your education rather than criticise so I hope that's the spirit you'll take my comments in.

Answer (score 3):

The `lower` will simply give you the address of that function which is *very* unlikely to be equal to `"n"`.

If you want to *call* it, you'll need to use `lower()`, as in:

```py
count = input("\nAre there any other bidders (y/n)?:\t").lower()
```

The following transcript shows the difference:

```py
>>> print("Hello".lower)
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x7f4e525fc6f0>
>>> print("Hello".lower())
hello
```